# @Name within repeat

Tags: xpages, repeat

I have an app I am build which will allow the users to enter the approvers for each document manually.  I wanted to put this in a repeat control instead of hard coding all the fields in the xpage.  All is working as I want, except the names are stored in the document in the Canonical format.  I don't want to present this to the user, I want to just show the Abbreviated name.  I can't seem to get it working.  Below is my repeat. I want to put and @name around the value of ApproverName_#

Thanks in Advance

Walt

```xml
<xp:repeat
   id="repeat4"
    var="rowItem"
    indexVar="indexVar">
   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"]}]]></xp:this.value>

<xp:panel>
       <xp:repeat
           id="repeat3"
           var="fieldName">            
           <xp:label id="label31"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Approver - " + rowItem}]]></xp:this.value></xp:label><xp:label id="label33" value="Name"></xp:label>
           <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["ApproverName_"+rowItem]}]]></xp:this.value>
           <xp:inputText id="nameinputText"
            value="#{document1[fieldName]}"
            style="width:333.0px" rendered="#{javascript:!document1.isEditable()}">

           </xp:inputText>
<xp:inputText id="inputText9" value="#{document1[fieldName]}" style="width:333.0px">
           </xp:inputText>
           <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1"
                for="nameinputText">
                <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker
                nameList="peopleByLastName"
                addressBookSel="db-name" groups="false"
                people="true">
                <xe:this.addressBookDb><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Subset(@DbName(), 1) + "!!names.nsf"}]]></xe:this.addressBookDb>
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                </xe:this.dataProvider>
                </xe:namePicker></xp:repeat>
       <xp:repeat id="repeat5" var="fieldName">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["Title_"+rowItem]}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:label id="label32" value="Title"></xp:label>

        <xp:inputText id="inputText10"
        value="#{document1[fieldName]}">
        </xp:inputText>
       </xp:repeat>
       <xp:repeat
           id="repeat6"
           var="fieldName">
           <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["ApprovalFlag_"+rowItem]}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText11" value="#{document1[fieldName]}">
                </xp:inputText>
                </xp:repeat>
         <xp:repeat
           id="repeat7"
           var="fieldName">
           <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["Reason"+rowItem]}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText12" value="#{document1[fieldName]}">
                </xp:inputText>
                </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Dojo Name Text Box instead of Input Field. It prevents typing, gives a better UX for removing entries, and does what you want out-of-the-box.

[image]